# Node js server not responding outside localhost centos

Tags: centos, node.js

I'm running a basic express server from CentOS but for some reason it is not responding outside of localhost, I have tried everything I have found on google but nothing works so far.

This is my express server: 
`app.listen(3000,"0.0.0.0");`

If I do `curl http://localhost:3000/` in the server it works fine.
If I curl to the ip of the server it doesn't work.

I already changed my iptables

`num  target     prot opt source               destination`

`1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80`

`2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80`

`3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3000`

There is currently a apache server running on port 80 with no problems.

I also tried setting a VirtualHost on apache but it didn't work either:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
ServerName SubDOmain.MyDomain.com
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

`</VirtualHost>`

There is another virtual host working fine that redirects to another DocumentRoot.

I'm running Node on root for testing purpose, but the node application owner is another user. All folders have 705 and files 664

Edit: I stopped apache and run my node app on port 80 and it working fine, I could access node app from my ip and domain.

Comment: Did you open the port in the firewall?

Comment: Isn't that what iptables are for?